# Improving versus Closing -- Help bad askers help themselves!

Tags: discussion

Following on from one of my comments on [This Question](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/2998/as-long-term-users-mature-on-the-site-do-they-get-less-patient), I think that we as a community can do a better job of helping the ***borderline*** questions improve to a point where they're actually worth answering and can provide continued value to the sysadmin community at large.

We certainly see a lot of [***BAD*** questions](https://serverfault.com/questions/363070/how-to-setup-cluster-in-ubuntu), but we also see many questions that [initially aren't great but with some gentle prodding can make sense](https://serverfault.com/questions/362884/cut-network-cables-in-cisco-2960-poe) and eventually gain some decent answers that might help 
someone new to the field figure out what's going on.

---

Answers on a postage stamp:

- Show us the questions you think can be improved.
- Show us the ones that are beyond hope.
- Show us the shining examples of ***GREAT*** questions that we can point to as examples of what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I personally don't participate in chat (but have a couple of times poked my head into VTC) would it be worth creating a chat room for the sole purpose of posting candidates for improvement? I've see questions that I think could be turned into something useful with a little help but which have been outside my area of expertise, so have been reluctant to edit them myself.

Comment: VTC could be renamed to *Improve or Close* or something like that and handle both cases, since the close traffic is quite low.

Comment: Great idea, @SvenW.

Comment: Re-purposing VTC would *probably* work, but I think any posts nominated for improving would have to be very clearly marked.  Right now, the people who post in VTC typically put only very terse notes about what they think is wrong with a post, it might not work if improvable posts are marked something like "imp."

Comment: I've renamed VTC Improve or Close lets see how this goes.

Comment: @Ward better yet, mark them with an [Imp symbol](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_FbFu1YBZ-Hw/S3qJyIuNzrI/AAAAAAAAAfg/dNxj-iyeR4M/s400/MaxImp.jpg).

Comment: Seems like a good idea to me -- I think oneboxing the crap and posting links with a little note about stuff that can possibly be improved/saved could work as a way to distinguish the questions.